# Trying to iterate through a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have json list. I would like to iterate "PrivateIP" through a list of dirctories and append to the empty list:

here's the code:

```
InstanceId = []
message = [{"SNowTicket":"RITM00001","ServerIPList":[{"PrivateIP":"182.0.0.0", "HostName":"ip-182-0-0-0.ec2.internal", "Region":"us-east-1", "AccountID":"12345678"}, {"PrivateIP": "182.1.1.1", "HostName": "ip-182-1-1-1.ec2.internal", "Region": "us-east-1", "AccountID": "12345678"}],"Operation":"stop","id":"text-123"}]

for i in message:
    for key in i:
        print(key, i[key])
        instanceIds.append(privateIP)
```

output of the code:

It gives the values for all the keys. But i would only want the values for "ServerIPList" and iterate its values "PrivateIP"

```
SNowTicket RITM00001
ServerIPList [{'PrivateIP': '182.0.0.0', 'HostName': 'ip-182-0-0-0.ec2.internal', 'Region': 'us-east-1', 'AccountID': '12345678'}, {'PrivateIP': '182.1.1.1', 'HostName': 'ip-182-1-1-1.ec2.internal', 'Region': 'us-east-1', 'AccountID': '12345678'}]
Operation stop
id text-123
```

i want to iterate the values for "PrivateIP" inside the dict of "ServerIPList" and append their values in the empty list "InstanceIds"

```
InstanceId = ["182.0.0.0", "182.1.1.1"]
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Hint: you don't need to iterate over the keys. You already know which key you want, so use that one directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for accessing the contents of the list message, we have to iterate through it `for i in message:`.

for accessing the ServerIPList in every i we have to make another for loop, i.e. `for j in i['ServerIPList']`

Then we can finally append the privateIP in the empty list.

The whole code for the same is as follows:

```
for i in message:    
    for j in i['ServerIPList']:
        InstanceId.append(j['PrivateIP'])
print(InstanceId)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for key in message[0].keys():
    if (key == "ServerIPList"):
        for i in message[0][key]:
            for key1 in i.keys():
                if (key1 == "PrivateIP"):
                    InstanceId.append(i[key1])
# print instanceID
print(InstanceId)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.